# How to display the app switcher and the top bar on all monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, application-switcher

I use an external monitor and I've just upgraded to Bionic Beaver 18.04 from Xenial Xerus 16.04. The differences are striking ok, but the most annoying are:

- when I <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>TAB</kbd> the app switcher is shown on the laptop monitor instead of the one where is the active window.
- the top bar (with clock and tray icons) is shown only on the laptop monitor.

Does anybody have a workaround?